# Event display in php with date difference

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to display the event by using date difference.. For example i'm having 3 fields in my table ie. start_date , end_date, publish_date. 
The event should be publish by publish_date to end _date.. How do i query and get that result. Any one pls

Comment: This question needs WAY more details before anyone can reasonably help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `BETWEEN` keyword:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $publish_date . "' AND  '" . $end_date . "'
```

Also if you want to give format like below

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') between STR_TO_DATE(publish_date, '%m/%d/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

hope this will sure help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date>='" . $publish_date . "' AND  date<='" . $end_date . "'; ?>
```